# Motherboard not displaying

Tags: display, motherboard, desktop-computer

I have read the manual for everything, checked that every connection was connected, replugged everything, checked and rechecked specs, but nothing comes up on the monitor. The PC turns on, the fans spin, the HDD does its usual clicking, and the keyboard and mouse receive power. What am I doing wrong?

Specs:

- mobo: ASUS M5A7L-M LX Plus
- Gateway tower
- CPU: AMD FX 8320
- GPU: GeForce 750 Ti OC
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Fury 8GB 1600 MHz
- PSU: Antec VP450
- SATA and DVD drives

Comment: Are you getting any beep codes?

Comment: There are too many possible things it can be, with little information to go on.  Troubleshooting tends to require open-ended exploration, a lot of sequential interaction, and speculation, none of which this site is set up to handle.  You will get much more effective help on a forum-style site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard & mouse lights are a good sign that the motherboard's doing something.

Have another monitor &/or video card to try? Or onboard video? I'd try that, could be incompatible or failed hardware.

Could try unplugging everything you can, one at a time & see if it starts working.

Comment: I just installed everything. This is a brand new pc build. Does that mean that the video is gonna run thru the card?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's set up now... maybe it's trying to use the onboard video (if there is any) but your monitor's  plugged into the video card, or vice versa. However it is now something's not working.

Comment: Ill try both, i was just using the onboard video because logically that would be default, but maybe it autodetected the card? Ill try again. BTW i think itnjust beeps once, but ill have to listen again.

Comment: It was the small ATX connector xD it wasnt pushed all the way in xD thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. I was thinking it could've been a switch stuck or the missing "cpu" power plug, but I thought an old computer of mine didn't turn on at all with that unplugged. If it's been helpful you can check-mark / select the answer to "close" it